# How to send a single quote as value in JSON webservice call

Tags: .net, asp.net, json

I'm trying to make a call to a JSON ASP.NET web service with .NET.

It is ok when I send `" { county : 'whatever' } "`, but I get a `500 Internal Server error` if I try for example `" { county : 'It\'s ok' }` ".

This is the code:

```
        request.CookieContainer = container;
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        data = " { county : 'It\'s ok' } ";
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // 500 Internal server error if i use { county : 'It\'s ok' }
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        String ss;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            ss = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I've found some posts with examples but I cannot make it work:

`" { county : \"whatever\" } "` and `" { \"county\" : \"whatever\" } "` also works.

But either of `" { county : \"It's ok\" } "`, `" { county : \"It\'s ok\" } "` or any other combination that contains a single quote in the variable work.

How can I send a single quote inside a JSON call?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your example do not contain valid JSON.

You can use [www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate any JSON strings.

**ALL** keys and string values should be surrounded by double qoutes.

A valid JSON string would be:

```
{ "county" : "It's ok" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{ "county" : "'" } // what's wrong with this?
```